# openmp simd was failed

Tags: c, openmp, vectorization, simd

i write a simple test code to use SIMD in openmp 4.0, but no accelerate i got.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define N 40000000

#pragma omp declare simd
double am(double a, double b){
    return a*b+a*b+a*b+a*b+a*b;
}

int main(){
    int i,j,s;
    double *  a=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
    double *  b=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
    double *  c=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);

    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        a[i]=0.56;
        b[i]=0.66;
    }

    clock_t t1=clock();
#pragma omp simd
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        c[i] = am(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    clock_t t2=clock();

    printf("%d\n",(t2-t1));
    scanf("%d",&s);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

the time with and without “#pragma omp declare simd” & “#pragma omp simd” are all 2900+ on my SNB.

what's more, warning "...\opm2.c(7,30): warning #13401: vector function was emulated" was accured....i really want to know why.

the same problem also accured in the followed code(enabled c99):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

int n=40000000;
int i,j,s;
double *a,*b,*c;

a=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
b=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
c=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    a[i]=0.56;
    b[i]=0.66;
}

clock_t t1=clock();
#pragma omp simd
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    c[i]=a[i]*b[i]+a[i]*b[i]+a[i]*b[i]-a[i]*b[i]+a[i]*b[i]+a[i]*b[i];
}
clock_t t2=clock();

printf("%d\n",(t2-t1));
scanf("%d",&s);
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);

return 0;
}
```

i really enabled openmp and the "#pragma omp padallel for" works well.i use intel c/c++ 2015.

if you can find the reason, really thanks, ありがとう, 多谢啦.

Comment: Please specify exact compilation flags used by you. Also, for second example, what diagnostics have been emitted by compiler?

Comment: In the second example, no any diagnostics wasemitted by compiler....I don't know "compilation flags" is what? when i use "#pragma omp pafallel for" I can see the number of threads, but how can i confirm if my code run with AVX?

Comment: compillation flags is everything you write to your compiler command: like -O3 -openmp and others, if you are using -O3 then try using -O0 I had a similar case where that helped

Comment: I have a check that the optimization in my icc is disabled (/Od), and my avx still don't work....but really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why...but on gcc 4.9 when I use -O1/O2/O3... the "#pragma omp simd" work well, and when I use -O0,it don't work. Ps:if you want to use avx rather than sse, don't forget "-mavx".